# Working with American Companies while Overseas

Tags: taxes, usa, remote, clients, travel

I've been googling this for days without a straightforward answer. My spouse is joining the foreign service, and we're both moving to Thailand next July on the US gov's dime. According to the foreign service materials on the state department website, I will probably have to pay Thai taxes for any income since I'll be living there for three years. I'm not too concerned about that. I'm a copyeditor for a few clients. I'm a 1099 contractor with them and get regular work with them. I've read a lot about foreign service spouses losing their W-2 jobs due to moving overseas because the company doesn't want to incur the tax risks. Will I encounter a similar thing when I tell my current companies about my move? Or does having a contracting relationship mean that nothing will change when I move? The best info I could find was that as long as you have a US address and bank account, you should be fine. But I just wanted to see if anyone else had a more thorough answer. Thanks!